# Creating invisible sections that can be indexed and added to glossary

Tags: tikz-pgf, glossaries, overlays, ocg, ocg-p

Basically I am trying to index, or make a glossary out of what is inside a picture. Let's say the pictures have apples and bananas, I am trying to add those to a glossary at the end where I should show each of the items with an individual picture.
The glossary should reference each picture/section rather than the page number, but I can comprimise to page numbers.
I have tried using [`ocg-p`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/ocg-p) package which defines nodes in tikzpicture environment as visible or invisible, but it seems like it is not possible to add an item to glossary from inside that environment, or I couldn't do it somehow.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[twoside,letter,11pt]{book}

% Packages -----------------------------------

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}%genel
\usepackage[splitindex,texindy]{indextools}
\usepackage{graphicx, xcolor}%resim eklemek ve üstünde oynayabilmek için
\usepackage[style=Ruled,valign=t, capposition=bottom]{floatrow}
\usepackage[strict=true]{csquotes}%fransız tipi tırnak işareti
\usepackage{todonotes} %Yapılacak Notları eklemek için
\usepackage{placeins}%Eklenen resim ve figürlerin bulundukları bölümde sabit kalmaları için
\usepackage[bibstyle=verbose, backend=biber, citepages=suppress, citestyle=verbose-trad1, firstinits=true, isbn=false,dashed=false]{biblatex} %Kaynakça için-------
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}%Metin-Dipnot bağlantısı için
\usepackage[acronym,nomain,xindy]{glossaries}%sözlük yapımı için

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ocg-p}
% ------------------------------------------------

% The glossary ---------------------------------------------

\newglossary[glg]{İşaretListesi}{gls}{glo}{İşaret Listesi}

%-------------------------------------------------------

\makeglossaries

% Some glossary elements that refers to the elements in the pictures -----------------------------------

\newglossaryentry{G1}{name={G 1}, description={image}, type=İşaretListesi}
\newglossaryentry{T14}{name={T 14}, description={image}, type=İşaretListesi}
\newglossaryentry{A1}{name={A 1}, description={image}, type=İşaretListesi}
\newglossaryentry{B1}{name={B 1}, description={image}, type=İşaretListesi}
\newglossaryentry{Hiero3}{name={3}, description={image}, type=İşaretListesi}
\newglossaryentry{N25}{name={N 25}, description={image}, type=İşaretListesi}
\newglossaryentry{R2}{name={R 2}, description={image}, type=İşaretListesi}
\newglossaryentry{M23}{name={M 23}, description={image}, type=İşaretListesi}
\newglossaryentry{N35}{name={N 35}, description={image}, type=İşaretListesi}
\newglossaryentry{Aa1}{name={A a1}, description={image}, type=İşaretListesi}
    % ---------------------------------------------------------------------

    \begin{document}

    % Some Picture---------------------------------------------------

    \begin{figure*}[h]

    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=0]

    % The image of the picture which should be visible ---------------------------------

    \begin{ocg}[printocg=always]{Hiyeroglif P1-3}{hierop1x3}{1}

% Use any image you like in \includegraphics instead

    \node[inner sep=0pt] (hierop1x3) at (2,0) {\includegraphics[scale=1]{./Paragraf_1_3.eps}
    \caption[P 1: r1-r2]{ Hiyeroglif Çevirisi § 1-3}};

    \end{ocg}

    \begin{ocg}[printocg=never,listintoolbar=always]{MdC P1-3}{MdCp1x3}{0}

        % The elements inside the picture which should overlay the picture and should      
% always be invisible, while retaining the ability to show up in glossaries        
% and indexes ------------------------------------------


    \node[overlay] (MdCp1x3) at (2,0)
    {
    \gls{G1} \gls{T14} \gls{M23}

    };

    \end{ocg}

    \end{tikzpicture}

    \end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

I am not obliged to use `ocg-p` in anyway. I am looking for a solution where the elements of picture and the image is overlayed though, to avoid the excessive white space and it is crucial to reference those elements in a glossary at the end.

**Update**:
I also found that deleting:

```
\ifglsentryexists{.\spacefactor \sfcode `\char "0307\relax }{}%
{%
\gls@defglossaryentry{.\spacefactor \sfcode `\char "0307\relax }%
{%
```

in the .glosdef auxilary file made the glossary elements visible without having the need to define a newcommand in latex. I don't know if it could be marked as a general soluion though.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please transform your example into something compilable -- at the moment it is disrupted and incomplete.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer it should be compilable now, besides the includegraphics which points to a file in my hard-drive. Also I am not sure which packages are of absolute necessity, so I am giving all them instead. Sorry for the blunder, i didn't notice the differences between the entry list and the uses of \gls{X}

Comment: For the graphics file: `\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}` will disregard any image and display a black rectangle instead -- this is useful for testing purposes (or providing an MWE)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution. If we have

```
\newglossaryentry{A1}{name={Aa 1}, description={image for example}}
```

The trick is to use

```
\newglossaryentry{A1}{name={}, sort={Aa 1}, description={\hspace{-.8em} image for example}}
```

One can define a new command that does this job

```
\newcommand{\mtnewglossaryentry}[3]{%
\newglossaryentry{#1}{name={}, sort={#2}, description={\hspace{-.8em} #3}}}
```

To be used `\mtnewglossaryentry{A1}{Aa 1}{image for example}`

For other entries (standard) one can do as usual

```
\newglossaryentry{Bla}{name={Bla 1}, description={Bla bla bla}}
```

---

To reference the section use `\gls[counter=section]{A1}`

```
\documentclass[twoside,letter,11pt]{book}

\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newcommand{\mtnewglossaryentry}[3]{%
\newglossaryentry{#1}{name={}, sort={#2}, description={\hspace{-.8em} #3}}}

\mtnewglossaryentry{G1}{G 1}{image}
\mtnewglossaryentry{B1}{Bla}{image}
\newglossaryentry{Bla}{name={Bla 1}, description={Bla bla bla}} % standard
\mtnewglossaryentry{A1}{Aa 1}{image}
% ---------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}
\section{Foo}
X \gls{Bla} \gls{G1}\gls[counter=section]{A1}foo \gls{B1}bla bla\gls{A1}.

\section{Bar}
X \gls{G1}\gls[counter=section]{A1}foo \gls{B1}bla bla\gls{A1}.
\printglossary

\end{document}
```

Comment: This works for listing the glossary items that are in the ocg-p environment, so I am marking it as an answer, however I can't see the names of the glossary items which was to be expected I assume, though I can add the names to the descriptions before adding the individual picture. Would you mind explaining how and why this works?

Comment: Answer edited again. Sorry, the first edit was confusing.